# In how many ways can the elements be divided into 2 groups given A set "a" having 6 elements?

Tags: permutations

A set "a" has 6 elements.In how many ways can the elements be divided into 2 groups?

Options given: 1) $62$  2) $31$  3) $52$  4) $32$

My Approach:

I divided the items into 2 unequal groups of 4 and 2,5 and 1,6 and 0,3 and 3.

I get

$6!$/$2!$ . $4$!=$15$

$6!$/$3!$ . $3$!=$20$

$6!$/$1!$ . $5$!=$6$

$6!$/$0!$ . $6$!=$1$

total=$42$

> Can anyone can give me hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: $6!/(2!\cdot 4!)$ is not the number of ways to break the elements into two groups.  It is the way to break 6 elements into a group of 2 elements and a group of 4 elements.  You must also add the ways to break the elements into a group of 1 element and a group of 5 elements as well as a group of 0 elements and a group of 6 elements and breaking the set into two groups of 3 elements.

Comment: @MichaelBurr By adding all i am getting wrong ans see the edit post please.

Comment: @anubhav How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are further restrictions, you have 6 slots. Each slot takes either the value 1 or 2. Therefore, the total number of partitions is 32.